# List files with possibility to compare size and give status

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have SQL archives, but seems one of them have less size from the others, is there any possible way to catch all sizes and to compare all of them and if some of them is less than some percentage ex: 20% to give bad status:

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         35846 Dec 10 23:00 0000001016.dwhext.gz
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         34869 Dec 11 23:00 0000000970.dwhext.gz
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         35134 Dec 12 23:00 0000001031.dwhext.gz
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users          9741 Dec 13 23:00 0000000265.dwhext.gz
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         32221 Dec 14 23:00 0000000911.dwhext.gz
```

Expected output to be:

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         35846 Dec 10 23:00 0000001016.dwhext.gz G
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         34869 Dec 11 23:00 0000000970.dwhext.gz G
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         35134 Dec 12 23:00 0000001031.dwhext.gz G
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users          9741 Dec 13 23:00 0000000265.dwhext.gz B
-rw-rw-r--    1 ort  users         32221 Dec 14 23:00 0000000911.dwhext.gz G
```

Comment: show your attempts..

Comment: Well my first idea was with awk to catch 5th column but then not sure is there any possible way to calculate them in awk so stuck on that idea, I'm not sure that if elif will be good idea just poor suggestion from my side ...

Comment: It's trivial, but it's not praticularly meaningful - gzip compresses stuff, compression ratios vary based on content. You might be better off verifying by actually decompressing the data.

Comment: I agree but in that case usual that is not change so much in the time, so in case when is different is good to have some status on it.

Comment: Anyway, given you've tagged this `perl` - take a look at the `stat` or `-s` functions.

Comment: Also: Don't parse ls output.

Comment: The idea with `stat` is very good but I take that output from the server and there is not allowed to use other commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty code (average is a simple *sum/occurence*)

```
awk '{A[$9]=$5;E[$9]=$0;T+=$5;N++}END{m=T/N;for(a in A) printf "%s %s\n", E[a], sqrt(( 1-A[a]/m)^2)>0.2 ? "B" : "G"}' YourFileList.txt
```

abs() does not exist so a `sqrt(x^2)` is used here

to keep same order, a 2 pass could be done

```
awk 'FNR==NR {div++;tot+=$5;next} FNR==1{m=tot/div} {if(sqrt(($5/m-1)^2) > 0.2) print $0 " B";else print $0 " G"}' sa* sa*
```

Comment: Give me syntax error on the question mark `)>.2 ? "B"`

Comment: try the full syntaxe `)>0.2 ? "B"` :-D

Comment: For some reason awk print everything on the first column but after that seems like the status is not in the first column when trying to use him for variable:
`awkcmd=$( awk 'FNR==NR {div++;tot+=$5;next} FNR==1{m=tot/div} {if(sqrt(($5/m-1)^2) > 0.2) print $0 "B ";else print $0 "G "}' tmp.data tmp.data)`
`# $awkcmd|head -1`
B w-rw-r--    1 ort  users         35846 Dec 10 23:00 0000001016.dwhext.gz
`# $awkcmd > tmp.1`
`# cat tmp.1|awk '{ print $1}'|head -1`
-rw-rw-r--

Comment: Well I catch the problem he just create ^M character for that reason reorder the columns ....